# Equivalent parallel pair of $j$-morphisms

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

I have a question about a definition used in nLab article on $n$-groupoids: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/n-groupoid

What does it mean that "every parallel pair of $j$-morphisms is equivalent for $j>n$? Surely, that's not a research question, but I nowhere found an answer. Does that mean that the corresponending equilizers on $j$-level are equivalences? (just a guess of mine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that between every two $j$-cells with the same domain and codomain ($j > n$), there is a $(j + 1)$-cell between them (which is necessarily an equivalence by the first condition of the definition on that page) exhibiting them as equivalent.

(Meta note: [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) is best suited for non-research-level mathematics questions.)

Comment: Addition to the meta note: also the category theory zulip [community](http://categorytheory.zulipchat.com) might be a good place to ask.

Comment: Further to @varkor's answer, I would recommend playing around with a homotopy-oriented proof assistant, for example [Globular](http://globular.science): it is an excellent way to acquire a hands-on intuition of "being equivalent up to higher cells". You can find a tutorial video for Globular by Jamie Vicary.